# Отрисовка Header в DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Возникла проблема при прокрутки или изменения размера таблицы с отрисовкой форм, то есть все сливается, как решить проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Пример кода

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, e.CellBounds);
            //e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, (DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background));
            //e.Handled = true;
            System.Drawing.Rectangle HeaderArea = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
            //HeaderArea = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.RowIndex);
            SolidBrush fillbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.Rectangle buttonFilter = new System.Drawing.Rectangle();
            buttonFilter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(HeaderArea.Left, 0);
            buttonFilter.Size = new Size(16, 16);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(fillbrush, buttonFilter);
            StringFormat FormatName = new StringFormat();
            FormatName.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            FormatName.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            HeaderArea.X = HeaderArea.X + 16;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name,
                this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font,
                new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                HeaderArea,
                FormatName);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        /*System.Drawing.Rectangle rtHeader = dataGridView1.DisplayRectangle;
        rtHeader.Height = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2;
        dataGridView1.Invalidate(rtHeader);*/
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(i,0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить прорисовку фона ячейки:

```
e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
```

При этом нет нужды обрабатывать событие `Scroll`.

---

Код можно чуточку упростить, за счёт использования других свойств/методов.
Кроме того, желательно освобождать все используемые в коде ресурсы.
Я бы написал как-то так:

```
if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1)
{
    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);

    var headerArea = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 16, 16);
    var contentArea = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + 16, e.CellBounds.Y, e.CellBounds.Width - 16, e.CellBounds.Height);

    using (var fillbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
    using (var formatName = new StringFormat())
    using (var fontBrush = new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(fillbrush, headerArea);

        formatName.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        formatName.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(),
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font,
            fontBrush,
            contentArea,
            formatName);
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

---

Также отмечу, что начиная с .NET 2.0 в WinForms по умолчанию используется GDI для прорисовки текста. То есть нужно использовать `TextRenderer.DrawText` вместо метода GDI+ `Graphics.DrawString`. Их вывод совсем незначительно, но различается.